# Accessing to different ports of different raspberries with dynamic-IP and 3G modem dongles

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, ssh-tunnel

I have about 100 raspberries, each of them installed in place without ethernet connection, so they have to transmit data to a main server with a 3G modem dongle. When the 3G connects the ISP gives a dynamic IP.

I have a solution of SSH reverse tunneling (explained here http://www.thirdway.ch/En/projects/raspberry_pi_3g/index.php) but I can just connect to port 22, and in the main server I have 100 different ports for each tunneling ... a nightmare.

Also I can not connect to other ports if I need, just 22.

About dynamic IP I know the "dyndns" (or similar) solution.

Is there any nice solution to operate with all of them easily, and can connect to ANY port ?

I would like to do things like:

- install munin (I need 4949)
- connect to  myraspberry45.mydomain.com  to 80
- ... or 22 if I want
- ...

Any idea?

Comment: why won't you just use vpn(i.e. pptp)?

Comment: or configure vpn over ssh https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH_VPN

Comment: Most of the time, devices connected over 3G connection are behind a NAT, so, a simple dyndns won't work.

Answer (score 0):

There could be other solutions which would be more complex. Though,In the beginning going with ethernet cables you might feel a little bit messy, you will eventually find them very reliable and simple. (obviously not in the physical sense.) Nevertheless, this should help. [Raspberry Pi Cluster](http://raspberrywebserver.com/raspberrypicluster/raspberry-pi-cluster.html)